# Calling a jQuery plugin's inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, closures

Here's the pattern of the jQuery plugin I am trying to write.

```
$.fn.dropdown = function(options) {

    var Dropdown = function(list, options) {
        // blabla
    };

    Dropdown.prototype.initialize = function() {
        // blabla
    };

    Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function(t) {
        // blabla
    };

    Dropdown.prototype.organize = function(t) {
        // blabla
    };

    Dropdown.prototype.resize = function() {
        // blabla
    };

    return this.each(function() {
        var list = $(this);
        var dropdown = new Dropdown(list, options);
    });

};
```

On instantiation it creates a new dropdown object.

```
var element = $('#element').dropdown();
```

How would I make it possible to call the inner resize() "on demand"?

```
element.resize();
```

Comment: u didn't even define the usage of your "resize" function

Comment: @blackmiaool yes he did. It's the last `prototype` call.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I mean the "usage" of it.

Comment: @blackmiaool The "resize" function updates some properties of the "dropdown" object and resizes the associated DOM object upon these updates.

Comment: I still can't get what kind of "on demand" do u want. Maybe a mutation observer can help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver @user6865443